# System.Data.Common - DbConnection string

Tags: dbconnection

I have a question, how should I make connection string using DbConnection? I am using SQL server. I tried looking in google for it, but no clues, so I ask u.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ ?

Comment: @stuartd Ty for info, but i looked in it too.

Comment: Are you looking for [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) then? That's the subclass of DbConnection used to connect to Sql Server.

Comment: @stuartd Sql is subclass of this then?

Comment: Yes. DbConnection is an abstract class, so you can't create one directly.